# Is there a name for this differential operator and/or its corresponding spectrum?

Tags: sp.spectral-theory, dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a real, compact, orientable manifold and let $X$ be a vector field on $\mathcal{M}$.  Consider the functional

$$E(f) = \int_{\mathcal{M}} X_p(f)^2 dV$$

where $X_p(f)$ is the directional (Lie) derivative of $f$ along $X$ at the point $p$ and $dV$ is a volume form on $\mathcal{M}$ -- this functional essentially measures the total amount of change in $f$ along $X$ over all of $\mathcal{M}$ in the $L^2$ sense.  Then $\delta E(f)$ is a differential operator whose eigenspectrum

$$\delta E(f) = \lambda f$$

(for $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$) yields the critical points of $E$ over the set of functions with unit norm.  Is there an established name for this operator (or functional) and/or its corresponding eigenspectrum?

The prototype for this operator is Dirichlet's energy

$$\int_{\mathcal{M}} ||\nabla f||^2 dV$$

which has as its (unit-norm) critical points the Laplacian eigenspectrum

$$\nabla^2 f = \lambda f,$$

the main difference being that Dirichlet's energy measures the total *gradient*, i.e., the change in all directions, rather than just the change along a particular direction at each point.

Comment: One small comment is that compact orientable manifolds do not come with a preferred volume form.  As your prototype suggests, you are perhaps working on a compact, orientable *riemannian* manifold.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I would have thought that critical points of E would correspond to zeros of dE. I.e., elements in the kernel of the corresponding differential operator, rather than just eigenvectors. 

Comment: José: I nearly added that condition, but decided to write "a volume form" rather than "the volume form" instead.  (Hopefully that's sufficient, though now I'm  uncertain whether a choice of volume form induces a Riemannian metric.)

Comment: Joel: you are correct -- the spectrum comes from critical points of the functional over the set of functions with unit norm (I was so used to working with this setup that I forgot to mention it!).  Fixed above.

Comment: @fuzzytron: 1st, I agree, it looks much better now you've mentioned the unit norm condition. 2nd, your problem makes perfect sense with just a volume form. This is enough to give you an L^2 inner product on functions and for your differential operator to make sense. You don't need a metric for your question to be meaningful. However, for future reference, it's important to note that a volume form is strictly less information than that given by a metric - there are many different metrics which have the same volume form. (It's enough to see this is true for inner-products in linear algebra.)

Comment: In fact it is not clear to me that a volume form gives _any_ information. The following seems at least plausible (some sort of underdetermined PDE?): "Given a closed manifold M and two volume forms w, w' with total volume 1, there is a diffeomorphism M -> M taking w to w'." Anyone know a nice proof?

Comment: @Tom Church: your claim is true and I've even seen a proof kicking around Mathoverflow somewhere, although my lazy search didn't turn it up. Despite this, naively of course a volume is <i>some</i> additional information. Different volume forms are different, even if they are equivalent. Put another way, there is no canonical choice of diffeo which takes w to w', because you can always compose with a w-preserving diffeo. On the other hand if by "information" you mean "information up to diffeomorphism" then of course I agree with you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an simple explicit formula for your operator in terms of known operators. To see this, note that $\delta E_f(g)$ (the differential of $E$ at the function $f$ in the direction $g$) is equal to
$$
2 \int X(f) X(g) dV = 2\int \left[L_X(g X(f) dV )-g\left(X(X(f)) dV+X(f)L_X(dV)\right)\right]
$$
where $L_X$ is the Lie deriviative with respect to $X$. Now, $\int L_X(\alpha) = 0$ for any top degree form $\alpha$, so we get
$$
\delta E_f(g) = - 2 \int_X g \left[X(X(f)) + X(f) div(X)\right]dV
$$
where the divergence of $X$ is defined by $div(X)= L_X(dV)/dV$. So, using the $L^2$-inner product on functions, we can interpret the 1-form $\delta E$ as the differential operator
$$
D :f \mapsto  - X(X(f)) - X(f) div(X).
$$
(This is the same way that the differential of Dirichlet energy is seen as the Laplacian.)

Note that the leading order part of D is just $X^2$ and so, in particular, $D$ is not elliptic. You'd expect this, of course, because $E$ only sees the change of $f$ in the $X$-direction.